# Open() system call doesnt work in combination with DIR directory pointer

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

Open() system call doesn't work in this code. However, they work normally if not used with combination to directory pointer. here i have used file->d_name to access the string base address to open the file but it doesn't work and prints error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<dirent.h> 
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/dir.h>

int main()
{
  DIR* d=opendir("DDD");
  struct dirent* file;
  int fd;
  char WBUFFER[]="IO OS system calls\n";
  char RBUFFER[100001];

  while((file=readdir(d))!=NULL)
  if(strlen(file->d_name)>=10)
    {
      if((fd=open(file->d_name,O_RDWR,0))==-1)
        printf("error\n");
      read(fd,RBUFFER,101);
      printf("%s",RBUFFER);
      close(fd);   
    }
  else if(strlen(file->d_name)>=3)
    { 
      if((fd=open(file->d_name,O_RDWR,0))==-1)
      printf("error2\n");
      write(fd,WBUFFER,50);
      close(fd);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file->d_name` contains just the file name, not the relative or absolute path which `open(2)` requires. That's why `open()` fails (unless you happen to have files with the same name in your current directory as the directory `DDD` has).

You need to prepend the directory name to `file->d_name` using `snprintf()`, like:

```
char buf[PATH_MAX];
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "DDD/%s", file->d_name);
```

and use `buf` in your `open()` calls.

Answer (score 1):

So the dirent->d_name contains only the file name, not the path. If you're using a modern Linux or POSIX-2008 compliant system, a somewhat nice (as in, race-free) way of doing what you're doing is something like (shortened semi pseudo-code, filling in the details left as an exercise for the reader):

```
int dfd = open("DDD", ...);
DIR *d = fdopendir(dfd);
...
while ((file = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
    int fd = openat(dfd, file->d_name, ...);
    ...
}
```